# Any faster algorithm to find the least common multiple?

Tags: algorithms, least-common-multiple

To find the least common multiple of $a,b$, call it $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$, divide there product by there greatest common divisor. However, finding the gcd requires at most $\log n$ time. I am wondering if there is a faster algorithm than so.

Comment: This does not work everytime but if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $\text{lcm}(a,b)=ab$

Comment: @Raptor, just edited the question.

Comment: Almost any arithmetic calculation using $a$ and $b$ will require $\log n$ time (assuming $n=\min(a,b)$). What makes you think the lcm is significantly faster than, say, the sum $a+b$?

Comment: No, since gcd & lcm can be computed from each other by cancelling the other from $ab$ they have the same computational complexity in general.

Comment: I am just wondering, why down-voted? did I violate any rule?

Comment: Also, at most $\log n$ is pretty fast. Converting base $10$ to base $2$ is $\log n$ divisions.